# Как это сделать? Дополнительную фичу к приложению Spring boot, Spring boot REST

Tags: spring, rest, boot

Как владелец, я хотел бы иметь все возможные привилегии:
 - иметь возможность создавать других администраторов и пользователей.
 - иметь возможность утверждать членство новых пользователей.  [: если я добавлю их, нет необходимости утверждать их]
 - иметь возможность писать резюме в книги всех существующих пользователей.
 - иметь возможность оценивать книги всех существующих пользователей.
 - иметь возможность менять пароли пользователей.

Мне не нужно полное решение. Хотя бы направление, где и что посмотреть и.т.д.

Comment: Решение зависит от текущей архитектуры уже имеющегося кода. Способов сделать вами описанное - несколько десятков, сложно что-то конкретное сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал Юрий, способов реализовать описанный вами функционал несколько десятков(если не больше).
Что необходимо для реализации такого функционала?

- Необходимо продумать, какие модели будут в вашем приложении и описать их.
  Скорее всего, это будет модель User, Role, CV(если речь идет о Резюме для приема на работу), у модели User будет поле CV и Role, определяющая администратор он или нет и так далее.
- Далее Нужно создать слой работы с базой данных или DAO слой, с помощью классов которого вы сможете работать с бд. Тут стоит разобраться, что такое JPA, EntityManager и тд.
- Далее создания слоя Сервиса, в нем будет описана бизнес логика. Например, метод создающий нового пользователя, в котором будет описано условие, при котором пользователь будет подтвержден при создании(к примеру).
- Следом контроллеры, которые будут обрабатывать запросы - отдавать страницы представления(например в html), выполнять какие либо действия, которые приведут к изменению состояния бд.
- Ну и слой представления.
  В конечном итоге взаимодействие внутри приложения будет выглядеть следующим образом - 
  Пользователь вводит в браузер URL и нажимает Enter, тем самым отправляя запрос к нам на сервер, контейнер сервлетов(Tomcat, к примеру) определяет, к какому из контроллеров передать управление, пусть это будет GET запрос на получение главной страницы, для которой у нас в контроллере создан соответствующий метод

  ```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public class MainController {

      @GetMapping
      public String getMainPage() {
          return "main";
      }

  }
  ```

  так же у нас будет контроллер для администратора, который нужен для реализации описаного функционала

  ```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/admin")
  public class AdminController {
      @Autowired
      private final UserService userService;

      @PostMapping("/new-user")
      public void createNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
          user.setEnabled(true);
          userService.save(user);
      }

  }
  ```

  В нем мы принимаем пользователя и просим UserService(который спринг любезно нам заинджектил из-за аннотации @Autowired) его сохранить, предварительно поставив флаг, означающий, что пользователь активен в положение true.

  ```
  @Service
  public class UserService {
      @Autowired
      private final UserDao userDao;

      @Transactional
      public void save(User user) {
          userDao.save(user);
      }

  }
  ```

  В данном случае, у нас простая логика сохранения, так что сервис просто передает полученного пользователя в DAO. Это может показаться бессмысленным, но если нам нужно было бы так же выполнить перед сохранением какую-то сложную логику - этот слой был бы очень кстати, чтобы не мешать все в одну кучу.

  ```
  @Repository
  public class UserDAO {
      @PersistenceContext
      private final EntityManager entityManager;

      public void save(User user) {
          entityManager.persist(user);
      }

  }
  ```

  Воуля, у нас есть новосозданный пользователь в базе. По аналогии можно прописать в этих классах методы, которые будут изменять данные пользователей или любую другую логику.
  Чтобы доступ к к админскому контроллеру был только у пользователя с ролью Админа, необходимо подключить и настроить Spring Security. 
  Пробежавшись по описанному выше списку вещей и коду, вы можете понять, что вам неизвестно о Spring. Видите незнакомое слово - гуглите или ищите уроки по этой теме и будет вам счастье. Так же советую просто посмотреть уроки/статьи и другие примеры CRM на Spring. 
  Надеюсь, ответил на ваш вопрос.